# is there any reason to use non-clustered 36 NVARCHAR id with having increment PK SerialID at same time?

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

I'm new at handling with a program that should handle large data.
(not huge though, about few hundred thousands rows for a most frequently inserted table for a year).

It's my company's newly bought ERP designing platform.
it is designed to have NVARCHAR(36) of ParentID and RecordID for each row and basically use it all around. It has numeric incremental PK at the same time.

when I'm running my query tests especially where I have to join tables, or somewhen there should be parent with 2~3 child tables, this NVARCHAR(36) non-unique, non-clustered RecordID Indexes are just bothering me so much.

everytime I run a deployment to my database, it automatically resets all views and indexes so it is hard to reset things again.

is it ok to keep it this way? or is it recommended after finish designing the whole thing with the platform, I manually set things again? Really want to know if there is any reason it is designed this way

Comment: You will need to tell us what **concrete database system** you're dealing with - *SQL* is just the query language - used by most RDBMS - so that doesn't really help at all. Please add a relevant tag like `oracle`, `sql-server`, `postgresql` to your question!

Comment: Sql server it is!